# How to loop through AutoIdChilds in Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have this social app like twitter and when the user looks for another user I want to see if the logged in user follows the other user, but i don't know how to loop through and find out if the logged in user already follows the other one.

```
{
  "follower" : {
    "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : {
      "-KbHXdeiOfGXzvavuQ_5" : {
        "uid" : "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2"
      }
    }
  },
  "following" : {
    "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : {
      "-KbHXdehbkeMvDyzNpRE" : {
        "uid" : "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2"
      }
    }
  },
  "handles" : {
    "jcadmin" : "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2",
    "jcbest" : "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2"
  },
  "user_profiles" : {
    "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : {
      "about" : "Hello world",
      "handle" : "jcbest",
      "name" : "Juan Carlos Estevez Rodriguez",
      "profile_pic" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b..."
    },
    "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : {
      "about" : "Hello",
      "handle" : "jcadmin",
      "name" : "Juan Carlos",
      "profile_pic" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0..."
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Database, what i want will be something like this

```
   self.databaseRef.child("following").child((self.loggedInUser?.uid)!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let snapshot = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]

        if("The other user UID exists in the following")
        {
            self.followButton.tittleLabel = "Unfollow"
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `$autoId`, you can just use the follower/following user's `$uid` as the key.

```
"follower" : {
  "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : {
    "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2": true
  }
},
"following" : {
  "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : {
    "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2": true
  }
},
```

Then you can observe the value of /following/$uid/$userId, switch the snapshot value to determine whether it's a `Bool` equal to `true` or just `null`.

```
let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(
    withPath: "following/\(uid)/$userId"
)

ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    switch snapshot.value {
    case let value as Bool where value:
        // value was a Bool and equal to true
        self.followButton.tittleLabel = "Unfollow"
    default:
        // value was either null, false or could not be cast
        self.followButton.tittleLabel = "Follow"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Firebase's `push()`/`childByAutoId()` method is great for getting a collection that it guaranteed to have unique children and that is ordered chronologically, somewhat like an array in most other languages.

But your collection of users is of a different type: it is more like a set. In a set, each value can occur only once. In the Firebase Database you'd model a set like this:

```
{
  "follower" : {
    "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : {
        "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2": true
    }
  },
  "following" : {
    "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : {
        "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2": true
    }
  },
  ...
```

So this puts the `UID` as they key, guaranteeing that each follower can only be present once in the collection (since keys must be unique in their context). The value `true` is just there since the database cannot store a key without a value, it has no meaning.

Now you can access the users "followings" with:

```
self.databaseRef
    .child("following")
    .child((self.loggedInUser?.uid)!)
    .observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            print("Following \((child.key!))"
        }
    })
```